# how to pass parameters from jsp to java class using RESTFUL

Tags: rest

i hav created a jsp page from which i m taking some values and on submit it should pass the parameters to the java class using rest.

> < form id="payment" method="post" action="addtogroup">
>
> < ol style="padding: 0;">
>
> < li>< label for="groupId">Group id:< /label>
>
> < input type="text" id="groupId" name="groupId"/>
>
> < br />
>
> < li>< label for="vendorId">Profile Id :< /label>
>
> < input type="text" id="vendorId" name="vendorId"/>
>                           
>       < li>
>                          < input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
>                           < br />
>                   < /ol>
>     < /form>

and the java code is:

> @RequestMapping(value = "/addtogroup/{groupId}/{vendorId}",method = RequestMethod.POST)

```
public String addtoGroup(@ModelAttribute("groupId") String groupId,@ModelAttribute("vendorId") String profileId){       
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
     String username = auth.getName();
     System.out.println("group id is="+groupId);
     System.out.println("profileId  is="+profileId);
     System.out.println("username  is="+username);
     grpDao.addToGroup(groupId,profileId,username);

    return "addtogroup";
}
```

> when i type [http://localhost:8080/biznex/rest/addtogroup/2/13] in the address bar directly the code is executed.
>   but when i click submit button in the jsp i get page not found error.
>   plz help me out.

Comment: When you type in address bar request method is GET, so on your server side you need to mention to accept this call using POST

Comment: and when i change the action="addtogroup/2/13" in the form tag then its executed but the values from the textbox is not taken. is there anything i need to change in the action attribute in the form tag in jsp

Comment: Got it, your are accepting groupId and vendorId in curly braces from path attributes ((@RequestMapping(value = "/addtogroup/{groupId}/{vendorId}")). You should accept these as Form parameters and not as path attributes if you want 2 and 13 to be accepted from FORM parameters

Comment: still the same problem page not found. is there anything to change in the action attribute in form tag

Comment: no while trying form parameters you have changed path in request mapping  from "@RequestMapping(value = "/addtogroup/{groupId}/{vendorId}" to "@RequestMapping(value = "/addtogroup" right? can you please paste code with FORM parameters to verify

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/addtogroup/{groupId}/{vendorId}",method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public String addtoGroup(@ModelAttribute("groupId") String groupId,@ModelAttribute("vendorId") String profileId){

Comment: You are still accepting {groupId} and {vendorId} in path change these to @RequestMapping(value = "/addtogroup". For basics please refer: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp-code-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`< form id="payment" method="post" action="addtogroup">` This statement means submit the FORM data using POST method to the url "currentpath"/"addtogroup"

However, your RESTFUL Server side component expects the url in the form of `/addtogoup/{groupid}/{vendorid}` in a GET method

I would suggest you to have a JavaScript method which converts your form fields to the URI path- using jQuery or plain JavaScript

Comment: Is JS the only way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As thewhiterabbit wrote, you have to pass the complete REST url with the groupid and vendorid.

In order to build it you don't need to use JS, it's enough the spring tag library. Here, how it works:

```
 <spring:url value="/addtogoup/${form.groupid}/${form.vendorid}" var="actionURL"/>

 <form:form method="POST" action="${actionURL}"  modelAttribute="form">
```